# Linux properly identifies headset microphone, but Windows does not

Tags: linux, windows, audio, kernel

On my Dell 3542, the official Realtel Windows driver offered by Dell has issues identifying the microphone of my headset connected through the 3.55mm combo audio port. This is a known issue for the device.

However, Linux, using PulseAudio on Debian, works completely fine with the headset microphone using the same 3.55mm combo audio port. This clearly indicates that the issue is not hardware-related at all, but rather something is wrong with Windows or the sound driver downloaded from Dell. Also, tried other several Realtek drivers to no avail.

So, I thought about seeing what driver is used by the Linux Kernel so I can hopefully use the Windows equivalent version of it, here's where I need your help.

Below is the output of the command "sudo lshw -C sound".

[image: Sound Driver used by Linux Kernel]

Thank you.

Comment: You may find out the Linux driver coded directly for the kernel, and not available separately for Windows.

Comment: Please don't post text as images. It's not searchable, users relying on screen readers can't read it at all and it looks bad on high resolution screens. Use the code formatting. You can [edit] your question.